# Graph API : The request is unprocessable because it uses too many resources with SharePoint list to get SharePoint Items

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am admitting that there are same questions available for the same issue, but I have tried a lot like I have added Prefer: apiversion=2.1 , Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly and as well as I have created an Index on a column (Modified) to use that into the Filter but all the things are getting failed and I am getting too many resources error.
Please note: I have 15000+ Items in the SharePoint List

Comment: can you add your filter clause in detail?